# Jquery second click on sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, sorting, onclick

When I click on UP, DOWN, NEWEST, OLDEST div is sorted but only on second click remove class odd to all divs and add class to all even divs.

I need do it on first click in same time with sort.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   
   jQuery('.vse:even').addClass('odd');
   /*ZOBRAZOVANIE KATEGORII*/
   jQuery('.vsetky').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.vse').show().removeClass('odd');
    jQuery('.vse:even').addClass('odd');
   });
 
    jQuery('.pozemne').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.hos, .inz').hide().removeClass('odd');
    jQuery('.poz').show().removeClass('odd');
    jQuery('.poz:even').addClass('odd');
   });

    jQuery('.inzinierske').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.hos, .poz').hide().removeClass('odd');
    jQuery('.inz').show().removeClass('odd');
    jQuery('.inz:even').addClass('odd');
   });

    jQuery('.hospodarske').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.inz, .poz').hide().removeClass('odd');
    jQuery('.hos').show().removeClass('odd');
    jQuery('.hos:even').addClass('odd');
   });

 /*ZORADENIE PODLA DATUMU*/
 jQuery('.najnovsie').on('click', function () {
  jQuery(".vse").sort(function(a,b){
      return new Date(jQuery(a).attr("data-date")) > new Date(jQuery(b).attr("data-date"));
  }).each(function(){
      jQuery(".vse").removeClass('odd');
      jQuery(".vse:visible:even").addClass("odd");
  }).each(function(){
      jQuery(".content").prepend(this);
  })

 }); 

  jQuery('.najstarsie').on('click', function () {
  jQuery(".vse").sort(function(a,b){
      return new Date(jQuery(a).attr("data-date")) < new Date(jQuery(b).attr("data-date"));
  }).each(function(){
        jQuery(".vse").removeClass("odd");
        jQuery(".vse:visible:even").addClass("odd");
  }).each(function(){
      jQuery(".content").prepend(this);
  })
 });

    /*ABECEDNE ZORADENIE*/
    jQuery('.zostupne').on('click', function () {
        jQuery(".vse").removeClass("odd");
        jQuery(".vse:visible:even").addClass("odd");
        var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = jQuery('.vse').sort(function(a, b) {
       if (a.textContent > b.textContent) {
         return -1;
       } 
       else {
         return 1;
       }
     }).appendTo('.content');
     });

     jQuery('.vzostupne').on('click', function () {
        jQuery(".vse").removeClass("odd");
        jQuery(".vse:visible:even").addClass("odd");
        var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = jQuery('.vse').sort(function(a, b) {
       if (a.textContent < b.textContent ) {
         return -1;
       } 
       else {
         return 1;
       }
     }).appendTo('.content');
     });

     /*PRIDANIE BACKGROUNDU NAVIGACII*/
     jQuery('.inline').on('click', function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
       });
});
```

```css
main {
    padding-top: 110px;
}
.inline {
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    padding: .5em;
}
.odd{
background:yellow;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="navigation">
  <div class="inline vsetky" value="Vsetky">ALL</div>
  <div class="inline pozemne" value="Pozemne">POZ</div>
  <div class="inline inzinierske" value="Inzinierske">INZ</div>
  <div class="inline hospodarske" value="Hospodarske">HOS</div>
  <div class="inline zostupne">UP</div>
  <div class="inline vzostupne">DOWN</div>
  <div class="inline najnovsie">NEWEST</div>
  <div class="inline najstarsie">OLDEST</div>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="vse poz sortme" position="Pozemne" data-date="26 Aug 2015">
   ČOV a kanalizácia - Viničné
  </div>
  <div class="vse poz sortme" position="Pozemne" data-date="24 Sep 2011">
   Administratívna budova ČOVSPOL - Bratislava, Mlynská dolina
  </div>
  <div class="vse poz sortme" position="Pozemne" data-date="25 May 2013">
   27 bytových jednotiek Podunajské Biskupice, Bratislava
  </div>
  <div class="vse inz sortme" position="Inzinierske" data-date="28 Aug 2002">
   Rekonštrukcia a intenzifikácia ČOV Lučenec
  </div>
  <div class="vse hos sortme" position="Hospodarske" data-date="21 Aug 2018">
   Skloplast Trnava
  </div>
  <div class="vse poz sortme" position="Pozemne" data-date="26 Aug 2014">
   Kaufland Bratislava
  </div>
  <div class="vse poz sortme" position="Pozemne" data-date="24 Aug 2010">
   Výstavba ČOV - obec Kuchyňa
  </div>
      <div class="vse poz sortme" position="Hospodarske" data-date="21 Aug 2020">
   Akloplast Trnava
  </div>
  <div class="vse poz sortme" position="Pozemne" data-date="26 Aug 2004">
   Daufland Bratislava
  </div>
  <div class="vse hos sortme" position="Pozemne" data-date="24 Aug 2000">
   Dýstavba ČOV - obec Kuchyňa
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here is jsfiddle:

```
  [https://jsfiddle.net/ynLhodds/][1]
```

Comment: Simply move your remove and add class calls to the end of the function after appending the content `}).appendTo('.content');`

Comment: Great! That works, thank you so much :)